# Displaying multiple data in react native

Tags: react-native

I am pretty new to react native. I am currently grabbing data from my node.js and trying to show all the data I grabbed into my View. In react.js, i did

documnet.getElementById.append().

What is the best way to do it in react native?

my code looks something like this

```
class GlobalRankings extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
    }
    this.getGlobalRankings();
  }

  getGlobalRankings(){
    var request = new Request(checkEnvPort(process.env.NODE_ENV) + '/api/global_rankings', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type' : 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' })
    });
    fetch(request).then((response) => {
        response.json().then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
            for (var i in data.value){
              console.log(data.value[i]); //where i grab my data
            }
        });
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    })
}

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
// want my data to be here
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an array in state in constructor, `this.state = { arr: [] }`

Then you assign the data array you get from the response.

```
fetch(request).then((response) => {
    response.json().then((data) => {
        this.setState({ arr: data.array });
    });
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

Then in the component body,

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  {
   this.state.arr.map((value, index) => {
      return(
          <Text key={index}>{value.text}</Text>
      );
   })
} 
</View>
```